# gdb hangs on "quit()"

Tags: linux, gdb

When I want to close `gdb`, I frequently mistype

```
quit()
```

instead of

```
quit
```

Whenever that happens, `gdb` hangs indeterminately, and I end up using `kill -9 gdb_pid` to terminate it.

I would like to ask:

- why are the additional brackets `()` affecting the behaviour of `gdb` in this way?
- is there a better approach to deal with this issue? **e.g.**
  redefine `quit()` as `quit`, a `patch`, simply learn why `()` are bad ...

Version of `gdb` is `7.11.90.20161005-0ubuntu2`.

Comment: What version of gdb? 8.0.1 on Arch Linux just tells me: ``A syntax error in expression, near `)'.``

Comment: @muru good to know that it has been fixed (:

Comment: Possible confusion with `call quit()` to make a function call but those tend to require a `call` on them (I instead use control+d or EOF to exit gdb...)